# How to use Ajax MaskedEdit with certain date format?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

We have a text box, where the user can input date. The only valid date allowed is `MM/dd/yyyy`. After going through all the trouble, I think `MaskedEditExtender` is the best choice. But I have some problems using it. Following is my ASPX code,

```
<div>
    Date: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
        CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
        CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
        CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" 
        Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>         
</div>
```

Here are my questions:

1. After I added the `MaskedEditExtender`, when I pick up a date from calendar, it won't write to the text box.
2. When I type some date in the text box, it will become 01-01-2011, not 01/01/2011, which is what I want.
3. Should I use `CompareValidator` or `MaskedEditValidator`? Since I want to make sure the date like 02/29/2011 is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. I try it on my own and everything works perfect.

So, I suggest you to try this code on a separate project solution to see if there is any other problem.

About 3th question, probably you need to use MaskedEditValidator if you need to validate the inserted date. You should use CompareValidator if you need to compare some dates for example.

Here is a good example of using MaskedEditValidator:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MV_Date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
            ControlExtender="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid Date"
            IsValidEmpty="False" />
```

Comment: what is the different between MaskedEditValidator or the CompareValidator?

Comment: As I wrote before the CompareValidator should be used to compare the value of one input control to the value of another input control or to a fixed value, and MaskedEditValidator verifies that the input text matches the pattern specified in the MaskedEdit extender. So for your question you should use MaskedEditValidator to make sure if date is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly. Just add latest version of ajax control toolkit.